# .htaccess: redirect works but, rewrite doesn't

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URLs from directory B to A.

Rewrite rule in .htaccess of directory B

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /A/xyz [NC,L]
```

Rewrite rule in .htaccess of directory A

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . index.php
```

After doing this when I hit *example.com/B/* results for index.php are rendered.
Whereas, when I change the rewrite to a redirect

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /A/xyz [NC,L,R]
```

It gets redirected properly to *example.com/A/xyz*

Rewrite incorrectly renders index.php. I want to render *example.com/A/xyz* when I hit example.com/B/. Using my current rewrite pattern and the substitution works only if I add the [R] flag to the rewrite. And I do not want to redirect, I only want to rewrite internally to the specified substitution.

Comment: Since the first version already does what you want, what is your problem?

Comment: You should remove the _php_ tag on this question

Comment: @OlafDietsche the first version incorrectly renders index.php. I want to render example.com/A/xyz when I hit example.com/B/ . Using my current rewrite pattern and the substitution works only if I add the [R] flag to the rewrite. And I do not want to redirect, I only want to rewrite internally to the specified substitution.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. When `/A/xyz` is a real file, `index.php` will not be used. Maybe another rule or .htaccess file in the parent directory jumps in.

Comment: @OlafDietsche is it possible that a parent directory or another rule only affects the rewrite and not a redirect?

Comment: I don't think so, but a redirect forces a new request from the client, whereas a rewrite restarts the URL rewrite loop.